# Does passing a reference to a fstream object preserve its position?

Tags: c++, fstream

I have the following code:

```
inline int write_int(std::fstream &file, int input){
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(input), sizeof(int));
}
```

Is this functionally equivalent to:

```
inline int write_int(std::fstream &file, std::streampos position, int input){
    file.seekp(position);
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(input), sizeof(int));
}
```

When the stream position is already at `position` before calling the function, or are there side-effects or main effects that make it function differently?

Comment: Think on what passing by reference means.

Comment: I'm pretty confident that calling `file.seekp` will essentially be a no-op if the stream is already positioned at that spot.  I mean, what else would it do?  I find your question title a bit misleading btw, passing something by reference doesn't mutate it in any way, why should it?